# How to upload a file to a slack channel using a bot

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack bot and the token starting with `xoxb` is used to upload a file to a channel.

I am using below format

```
curl -F token="${SLACK_TOKEN}" -F file=e2e.sh -F channel="${SLACK_CHANNEL}" -F  as_user=true https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

This throws

```
{"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the **@** in your `file=e2e.sh` argument to let curl know you want to transmit a file. The following should do the trick:

```
curl \
  -F token="${SLACK_TOKEN}" \
  -F file=@e2e.sh \
  -F channel="${SLACK_CHANNEL}" \
  -F as_user=true \
  https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

p.s. Breaking a long curl into multiple lines can help you see things more clearly ;)